# searching large data in matlab: database vs tall array?

Tags: database, matlab, large-data

I have csv files with a total of about 100 million rows of data (14 columns).  Each row has a unique numeric key.

Other code I'll be running in Matlab will need to grab a row from the table above based on the numeric key.  Overall, it will need to do this tens of thousands of times.  A database seems like a good choice, but would a tall array be faster?  I've never worked with tall arrays and wondering if it's worth learning about them for my situation.

Comment: Can you say more about the code you're looking to run on a `tall` array? If you can express your operation as a grouped operation (i.e. using `groupfun` or `findgroups` and `splitarray`), then `tall` might be a reasonable option. If your MATLAB code is looping over finding a single row and then operating on it, this is not likely to perform well using `tall` - as each operation to find a row needs to iterate through the data.

Comment: the code uses a loop, each iteration finds a single row and operates on it, then repeats.  So I guess I'm better off using a database.

Comment: Yes, if you really need random access like that, and there aren't `tall`-specific methods to help, then that might be a better way forward.